# How does the Sepolia Test Network work?

Tags: blockchain, testnets, sepolia, faucets

How do Test Nets like Sepolia stay in operation? According to chat GPT hosting a node has no token or financial award so why do people do it?

In that case how are people supplying free faucets if there is not reward?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Ethereum Foundation, and some companies that provide services for Ethereum they run nodes, or provide funding.

Comment: Very interesting!  Thanks!